# Is it safe to run multiple XNA ContentManager instances on multiple threads?

Tags: xna, multithreading

My XNA project currently uses one ContentManager instance, and one dedicated background thread for loading all content.

I wonder, **would it be safe to have multiple ContentManager instances, each in it's own dedicated thread, loading different content at the same time?**

I'm prompted to ask this question because [this article](http://konaju.com/?p=27) makes the following statement:

> If there are two textures created at the same time on different
>   threads, they will clobber the other and you will end up with some
>   garbage in the textures.

I think that what the author is saying here, is that if I access one ContentManager simultaneously on two threads, I'll get garbage. But what if I have separate ContentManager instances for each thread?

If no-one knows the answer already from experience, I'll go ahead and try it and see what happens.

Comment: It's a good question, but *`If no-one knows the answer already from experience, I'll go ahead and try it and see what happens.`* should be done before asking this question.

Comment: Thanks @AustinBrunkhorst, I don't disagree, but this does make a nice place to share the answer once I find it don't you think?

Comment: The author of your linked article seems to be stating that creating textures is not thread-safe in XNA (ie: irrespective of how you use `ContentManager`). I have *never* heard this before - and I can't find anyone else making the same claim. But I have seen many people saying that it *is* safe, including original XNA team lead Shawn Hargreaves, in MikeBMcL's link (and several other places).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be fine. See: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/18034.aspx .

I disagree with the comment - "*If no-one knows the answer already from experience, I'll go ahead and try it and see what happens.* should be done before asking this question." - as regards this particular question since threading problems are often hard to tease out so it's, to me at least, better to ask since you might test, find nothing, go live, and have a lot of crash reports start coming in because of some small architectural difference on a particular chipset that exposes a race condition your testing on other chipsets missed.

Comment: Holy awesomeness, the thread you linked to I think has very relevant discussion, I'll have a good read through before accepting the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the a content tracker library (originally on CodePlex, but now available [here](https://github.com/dubajj/XNA-Content-Tracker)) to load content in background with no problems.

It lets you unload individual assets, force file read (for editors), know the relationship among assets... it's worth it.